# configire HTTPS on nginx docker container which hosts angular app

Tags: docker, nginx, https

I have my docker file which deploys angular app on nginx docker container. I need to make it work with https and I am creating the default-ssl.conf and copying it to the container. Currently I want it to work with localhost and we do not have any domain. Please advise if there is any way to have https working with localhost to use the deployed app on nginx docker container. Thanks!

1st Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY /meg /usr/share/nginx/html
ADD server.crt /etc/nginx/certs/
ADD server.key /etc/nginx/certs/
COPY default-ssl.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-ssl.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
RUN ls /etc/nginx/certs/
COPY /Home /usr/share/nginx/html
```

2nd Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
ADD server.crt /etc/nginx/certs/
ADD server.key /etc/nginx/certs/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
RUN ls /etc/nginx/certs/
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name localhost;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
    error_log /var/log/front_end_errors.log;
}
```

}

Two containers will be built using above docker files.

Comment: There is a conflict on port 443. What localhost:443 sould serve: `/usr/share/nginx/html;` or `proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;` ? And what is you error ?

Comment: edited the question. Please help.

Comment: Do you really need 2 Nginx containers for that? One is enough if you have a good `nginx.conf`

Comment: Is my nginx.conf good enough to get this working for https? I tried with once container with the nginx.conf in the question. It still doesn't work.